# Returning a list of Result fields using Flask-graphql

Tags: python, graphql, flask-graphql

So let's say, I have defined a field, `project` using `Graphene.Field` in my query. Now depending on the incoming query, the result may be a single project object or a list of proejct objects:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

   project = graphene.Field(Project,..) # Project is a class defined  elsewhere

   def resolve_project(self, args, info):
     # Implementation
```

How do I return a list of projects as response from my [Flask-graphql](https://github.com/graphql-python/flask-graphql) application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `graphene.List(Project, ...)` and it should work ;)

Comment: Are you sure? For me if I use `graphene.List(...)` it will always return a list.